# Solution of Schrodinger's equation driving by a Heaviside function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the the following equation with initial conditions:
$$
y''(t)+y'(t) \left(-\frac{f'(t,\tau)}{f (t,\tau)}+i~\omega \right)+y(t)~(f(t,\tau))^2=0\\
y(0,\tau)=0\\
y'(0,\tau)=1
$$

and
$$
f(t,\tau)=g(t+\tau)*h(t)
$$
where $\tau$ is some parameters where we can control, $g(t)$ is a known function, $h(t)$ is the Heaviside function.

If we know the the solution as a function of $\tau$ at center $t=t_0$, say, we know $y(t_0,\tau)$ at any $\tau$, is it possible to get the solution as a function of $t$ at certain $\tau=\tau_0$, ie., $y(t,\tau_0)$, without solving the equation directly?

PS: The above equation describes the time-dependent Schrodinger's equation of a two-level system, driving by a classical laser pulse. $y$ is the occupation probability of one state. $f$ is probational to the electric field.